# VBA Saving only Visible Data into New Sheet in the same Path

Tags: excel, vba, filter

I'm relatively new to VBA. I worked on the following code, which workED perfectly until I decided to filter for non-blanks before saving the sheet.

The idea is to save my sheet in the same path after filtering out any blank values. The new file will be values only in CSV. Again, all of that worked, except when it comes to filtering the data and saving the file.

Now I get the

> "Run-time error 438 Object doesn’t support this property or method"

on the code below

`ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SHEET1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy`

The full code

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

If Sheets("SHEET1").AutoFilterMode Then Sheets("SHEET1").AutoFilterMode = False

sDate = Format(Sheets("SHEET2").Range("F1"), "YYYY.MM.DD")
cell = "NAME - " & sDate
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SHEET1").Range("A:C").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="<>"
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SHEET1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
With ActiveSheet.UsedRange
.Value = .Value
End With

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & cell & ".csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV
End Sub
```

Comment: [`SpecialCells`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.specialcells) is a method of a `Range` object, not a worksheet.

Comment: Hi BigBen, how can I fix the code to only copy the visible with a worksheet object?

Comment: You can add a new workbook and then copy the visible cells into the first sheet.

Comment: You mean saving the results into a new sheet then saving that sheet into a new workbook? Is there a better way of doing that? Because the end goal is to save the sheet as a new workbook as values in CSV

Comment: Yes that is what I mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please read the code's comments and adjust it to fit your needs

**EDIT:** Adjusted a type in this row `sourceSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy targetWorkbook.Worksheets(targetWorkbook.Sheets.Count).Range("A1")`

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim targetWorkbook As Workbook
    Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet

    Dim formatDate As String
    Dim fileName As String

    Set sourceSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    ' Remove filter
    If sourceSheet.AutoFilterMode Then sourceSheet.AutoFilterMode = False

    If sourceSheet.Range("F1").Value <> vbNullString Then
        formatDate = Format(sourceSheet.Range("F1").Value, "YYYY.MM.DD")
    End If

    ' Set the new workbook file name
    fileName = "NAME - " & formatDate

    ' Filter the fileNames
    sourceSheet.Range("A:C").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="<>"

    ' Add new workbook and set reference
    Set targetWorkbook = Workbooks.Add

    ' Copy the visible fileNames in a new workbook
    sourceSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy targetWorkbook.Worksheets(targetWorkbook.Sheets.Count).Range("A1")

    ' Save the new workbook
    targetWorkbook.SaveAs ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & fileName & ".csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV

End Sub
```

Let me know if it works

Comment: Hello Ricardo! First of all, thank so much. I'm getting error 438 at this code. Thoughts?`sourceSheet.UsedRange.SpecialfileNames(xlfileNameTypeVisible).Copy`

Comment: I have a typo. See my EDIT. Copy the code again. Sorry!

Comment: Hi Ricardo, it worked perfectly. So basically you're telling Excel to Add a new sheet and paste the visible data then save that as CSV. Thank you so much, I've learnt a lot as usual.

Comment: Glad it worked. Let me know if you meed anything else

Comment: Hi. Please post a new question and include some sample of what the expected results looks like.

Comment: Hi Ricardo, [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60180683/vba-naming-the-new-workbook-using-a-phrase-cell-reference-and-date-from-a-cell)