# VBA Naming the New Workbook using a Phrase, Cell Reference, and Date from a Cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code that produces a new worksheet. I'm trying to name the new worksheet using a Phrase, the content in Cell 1, and the date in Cell 2. 
Cell 1 will contain some data that are inserted via Data Validation (4 options in total) and Cell 2 will have a date.

EXAMPLE:
Worksheet INPUTS Range C3. Cell 1 value = Trade Activities, Purchases, Sales...etc

Worksheet INPUTS Range C2. Cell 2 value = 2.11.2020

The new workbook's name will be "Client Name Trade Activities - 2.11.2020"

both Cell 1 and Cell 2 will be in the INPUTS worksheet

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim targetWorkbook As Workbook
Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
Dim formatDate As String
Dim fileName As String

Set sourceSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
If sourceSheet.AutoFilterMode Then sourceSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("INPUTS").Range("C3").Value <> vbNullString Then
    formatDate = Format(Sheets("INPUTS").Range("C3"), "YYYY.MM.DD")
End If
fileName = "Name - " & ActivityName & formatDate
sourceSheet.Outline.ShowLevels ColumnLevels:=1 
sourceSheet.Range("A:M").AutoFilter Field:=12, Criteria1:="<>0"
Set targetWorkbook = Workbooks.Add
sourceSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy targetWorkbook.Worksheets(targetWorkbook.Sheets.Count).Range("A1")
targetWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Columns("A:AC").EntireColumn.AutoFit
targetWorkbook.SaveAs ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & fileName & ".xlsx", FileFormat:=51
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some things to remember:

1. Define and reuse your variables whenever you can
2. Try to add comments to your code, explaining the purpose of what you're doing (your future self or whom ever is going to work with your files, is going to thank you)
3. Leave spaces between your code's main parts, so it's more readable

**EDIT:** Added error handler, for when user clicks "No" when asking to overwrite existing file

**Code:**

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim targetWorkbook As Workbook
    Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet

    Dim formatDate As String
    Dim fileName As String

    On Error GoTo CleanFail

    Set sourceSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    ' Remove filter
    If sourceSheet.AutoFilterMode Then sourceSheet.AutoFilterMode = False

    If sourceSheet.Range("F1").Value <> vbNullString Then
        formatDate = Format(sourceSheet.Range("F1").Value, "YYYY.MM.DD")
    End If

    ' Set the new workbook file name
    fileName = "NAME - " & formatDate

    ' Filter the fileNames
    sourceSheet.Range("A:C").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="<>"

    ' Add new workbook and set reference
    Set targetWorkbook = Workbooks.Add

    ' Copy the visible fileNames in a new workbook
    sourceSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy targetWorkbook.Worksheets(targetWorkbook.Sheets.Count).Range("A1")

    ' Save the new workbook
    targetWorkbook.SaveAs ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & fileName & ".csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV

CleanExit:
    Exit Sub

CleanFail:
    Select Case Err.Number

    Case 1004
        MsgBox "You cancel the process"
        Resume Next
    Case Else
        ' Do something else? handle it properly...
        MsgBox "Something went wrong..."
        Resume CleanExit
    End Select

End Sub
```

Let me know if it works

Comment: Thanks Ricardo! Works perfectly. I think I was missing .value in my attempt.

Comment: Hi Ricardo, I realized that after saving the reporting and running the tool again, I get a message to replace the existing file. When I click "No" I got error 1004, Application-Defined or object-defined error. Also, if I run the tool whole the new report window is open, I get error 9, Subject out of range.  Thoughts on these two errors? Ideally I would like to put a msg box stating to close the open window for error 9. And find a solution for error 1004.

Comment: Hi, I added the handler for error 1004. The other one, I didn't get how to reproduce it

Comment: Thank you! It seems like the Exit Sub is stopping that error from showing up! It works.

Comment: Hi Ricardo, just a follow-up question. What if I wanted to use the original excel sheets file name in naming the new file?

Comment: so the code for the file name will be `fileName = thisworkbook.name & formatDate` ??

Comment: I guess so. give it a try. let me know if it is what you're looking for.

Comment: Replace the `Thisworkbook.Name` with `Left(ThisWorkbook.Name, (InStrRev(ThisWorkbook.Name, ".", -1, vbTextCompare) - 1))`

Comment: That works. I added the Replace function in order to remove the xlsm from name of the PDF file. Thank you!

Comment: Hi Ricardo, I'm taking this to another level, and thought you'd might be interested [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60232912/vba-loop-through-a-file-path-and-run-a-code)