# VBA Loop Through a File Path and Run a Code

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I have the code below that I would like to run to all of the available excel files in a folder. Ideally, I would like to input the path of the folder into cell C3 in Sheet1 and the macro to apply the code to all of the existing files.

The code will simply save the second sheet of each file into a PDF version, it works perfectly standalone.

Sample Folder Path: 
C:\Users\MMMM\Desktop\Project X\ Project II

Suggestions on how to approach this?

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()



    Dim MyFolder As String, MyFile As String



    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

       .AllowMultiSelect = False

       .Show

       MyFolder = .SelectedItems(1)

       Err.Clear

    End With


    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Application.DisplayStatusBar = False

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual





    MyFile = Dir(MyFolder & "\", vbReadOnly)



    Do While MyFile <> ""

        DoEvents

        On Error GoTo 0

        Workbooks.Open Filename:=MyFolder & "\" & MyFile, UpdateLinks:=False


Dim ReportSheet As Worksheet

Dim allColumns As Range



    Set allColumns = Sheets("RT").Columns("N:S")

    allColumns.Hidden = True



    With Worksheets("RT").PageSetup

     .Zoom = False

     .FitToPagesWide = 1

    End With


Filename = ActiveWorkbook.Name



Cell = Replace(Filename, ".xlsx", ".PDF")

Set ReportSheet = Sheets("RT")


Sheets("RT").Select



Sheets("RT").PageSetup.Orientation = xlLandscape



ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _

    ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & Cell, _

    Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, _

    IgnorePrintAreas:=True, OpenAfterPublish:=True

0

        Workbooks(MyFile).Close SaveChanges:=False

        MyFile = Dir

    Loop


    'turns settings back on that you turned off before looping folders

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    Application.DisplayStatusBar = True

    Application.EnableEvents = True

    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual


End Sub
```

Comment: Suggest you use a built in dialog to get the folder path. Avoid using `ActiveSheet` and use specific, fully qualified sheets, including the specific workbook. SO is here to suggest fixes for code that fails or does not do what you expect. Take the coding in small steps. Get your code to do what you want to a specific file (hardwired) and nothing else. Then add code to operate only on a specific file type. Then loop files in a specific folder specified in your code (hardwired), Continue expanding capabilities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This needs a reference (see [this link](https://vbaf1.com/filesystemobject/create-microsoft-scripting-runtime-library-reference/))

It's untested (so let me know if anything comes up)

Basically:

1. As suggested by SmileyFtW it asks you for the root folder
2. Scans the subfolders for excel files (adjust the extension in code)
3. Process the DoSomething procedure where you export the file

**EDIT:** Added handle user cancel file select dialog

**Code:**

```
Option Explicit

' Add a reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime
' See https://vbaf1.com/filesystemobject/create-microsoft-scripting-runtime-library-reference/

Private Sub ProcessAllFilesInFolder()

    Dim FileSystem As Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Dim fileDialogResult As Office.FileDialog

    Dim folderPath As String

    Set FileSystem = New Scripting.FileSystemObject

    Set fileDialogResult = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

    With fileDialogResult
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Title = "Select a folder"
        If .Show = True Then
            folderPath = .SelectedItems(1)
        End If
        If .SelectedItems.Count = 0 Then Exit Sub
    End With

    ProcessFolder FileSystem.GetFolder(folderPath)

End Sub

Private Sub ProcessFolder(ByVal targetFolder As Scripting.Folder)
    Dim FileSystem As Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Dim File As Scripting.File
    Dim SubFolder As Scripting.Folder

    Set FileSystem = New Scripting.FileSystemObject

    For Each SubFolder In targetFolder.SubFolders
        ProcessFolder SubFolder
    Next

    For Each File In targetFolder.Files
        If FileSystem.GetExtensionName(File.Name) Like "xls?" And File.Name <> ThisWorkbook.Name Then
            DoSomething File.Path
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub DoSomething(ByVal filePath As String)

    Dim FileSystem As Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Dim ReportSheet As Worksheet

    Dim targetFileName As String

    targetFileName = Replace(ThisWorkbook.Name, ".xlsm", ".PDF")
    Set ReportSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")

    ReportSheet.PageSetup.Orientation = xlLandscape
    ReportSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
                    ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & targetFileName, _
                    Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
                    IgnorePrintAreas:=True, OpenAfterPublish:=True
End Sub
```

Let me know if it works!

Comment: Hi Ricardo, I put the code above together, so far it seems to get the job done, and I would like your thoughts about the code? do you see any problems that I might face with it?

Comment: Regarding your code, I'm getting a "Compile Error: User-defined type not definded" on the beginning of this sub `Private Sub ProcessFolder(ByVal targetFolder As Scripting.Folder)`

Comment: Hi! Sure. Have a look at the instructions at the begining of my answer. This needs a reference (see this link)....

Comment: Hi Ricardo, when I run the macro, I get a pop-up to select a folder. When I click Cancel, I get the following error "Run-time error '5': Invalid procedure call or argument" on this code `MyFolder = .SelectedItems(1)` any idea on how to fix this? I tried inserting the if .show = true, which caused a huge error I've never seen before!

Comment: Hi! please see my edit.Added this line: `If .SelectedItems.Count = 0 Then Exit Sub`

Comment: Perfect, that worked. Thank you Ricardo once mote! Is there a way to show a msg once the process completed successfully, preferable with the number of files that were converted?? How can I count the times the loops occured successfully?

Comment: Aswesome. You can add a `Msgbox "your message"` at the end. for the counter, add a variable like `Dim counter as long` and you can increment it by `counter = counter + 1`

Comment: How will the Counter be linked to the number of loops?

Comment: Put the declaration below `Option Explicit` (that way is available to all procedures) and then increment it inside `DoSomething` sub, finally in the `msgbox` line add `..."your message " & counter`

Comment: Oh nice, I see the logic in there now!! That's smart, thank you. Now I got the times the loop ran and the the time it took the macro to be completed! Figured out all the variables that I didn't declare too!! Thank you Ricardo, I think this project is now completed!

Comment: Hi Ricardo, I change the framework a bit. The Tab name which to be converted will be reflected to a cell value. I wrote the following code in order to inform the user to add a Tab name in case it was missing. I would like it to exit the Sub after showing the message. Thoughts? `If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C7").Value = vbNullString Then

 

MsgBox "Enter Tab Name"

 

End If`

Comment: before the `end if`add `Exit Sub` (in a separate line)

Comment: Thank you, so as long I don't end the If statement, I can put other lines of codes as part of Then, correct?

Comment: Please add another question so I can see exactly the code as you're preparing it

Comment: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60312133/vba-compile-error-syntax-error-for-saving-excel-in-pdf-for-excel-2019) Thoughts on this error?