# VBA Hiding Columns and Rows using Cell Reference

Tags: excel, vba, variables

I would like to hide certain columns and rows based on inputs into certain cells, to make the code easily editable.

Furthermore, if the reference cell/range is empty, then I would like to continue the code without hiding any rows or columns.

Columns to Hide: based on cells C8:D8

Rows to Hide: based on cells C9:D9

This is where the logical fest should take place

```
reportColumnsAddr = settingsSheet.Range("C8").Value & ":" & settingsSheet.Range("D8").Value

reportRowsAddr = settingsSheet.Range("C9").Value & ":" & settingsSheet.Range("D9").Value
```

Current Code

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()


Dim MyFolder As String, MyFile As String
Dim StartTime As Double
Dim MinutesElapsed As String
Dim Filename As String
Dim Cell As String
Dim Counter As Long


If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C7").Value = vbNullString Then

MsgBox "Enter Tab Name"
Exit Sub

End If

With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
.AllowMultiSelect = False
.Title = "Select a Folder"
If .Show = True Then
MyFolder = .SelectedItems(1)

End If



If .SelectedItems.Count = 0 Then Exit Sub
Err.Clear
End With


Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

MyFile = Dir(MyFolder & "\", vbReadOnly)

StartTime = Timer

Do While MyFile <> ""
DoEvents
On Error GoTo 0

Workbooks.Open Filename:=MyFolder & "\" & MyFile, UpdateLinks:=False


Dim settingsSheet As Worksheet 'Source
Dim reportSheet As Worksheet 'To convert to PDF
 Dim targetColumnsRange As Range 'feeds from source
Dim targetRowsRange As Range
Dim reportSheetName As String 'source sheet with the target's sheet name
Dim reportColumnsAddr As String
Dim reportRowsAddr As String
' Set a reference to the settings sheet

Set settingsSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") ' source

' Gather the report sheet's name

reportSheetName = settingsSheet.Range("C7").Value ' good

reportColumnsAddr = settingsSheet.Range("C8").Value & ":" & settingsSheet.Range("D8").Value

reportRowsAddr = settingsSheet.Range("C9").Value & ":" & settingsSheet.Range("D9").Value

Set reportSheet = Sheets(reportSheetName) 

Set targetColumnsRange = reportSheet.Range(reportColumnsAddr)

Set targetRowsRange = reportSheet.Range(reportRowsAddr)

targetColumnsRange.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
targetRowsRange.EntireRow.Hidden = True


With reportSheet.PageSetup
.Zoom = False
.FitToPagesWide = 1 '.FitToPagesTall = 1
End With

Filename = ActiveWorkbook.Name

Cell = Replace(Filename, ".xlsx", ".PDF")

reportSheet.Select
reportSheet.PageSetup.Orientation = xlLandscape

ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _

ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & Cell, _

Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, _

IgnorePrintAreas:=True, OpenAfterPublish:=False

Counter = Counter + 1

0

Workbooks(MyFile).Close SaveChanges:=False

MyFile = Dir

Loop

'turns settings back on


Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

MinutesElapsed = Format((Timer - StartTime) / 86400, "hh:mm:ss")

MsgBox "Successfully Converted " & Counter & " Files in " & MinutesElapsed & " minutes", vbInformation

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### A couple of thoughts about your code:

> Dim MySheet As String

1. As `mySheet` is referring to the sheet name, be clear about it.

   Rename the variable as `Dim mySheetName as String`

---

> Set ReportSheet = Sheets(MySheet)

2. When setting the reference to the report sheet use full quilifying to the object.

   Add `Set reportSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(mySheetName)`

---

> I tried using the following logic, but it did not work, since I'm not able to insert " as part of the naming to properly create my variable.

3. To insert a double quote character, you can use: `char(34)`

   e.g. `TEST1 = "(" & Chr(34) & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C8").Value & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D8").Value & Chr(34) & ")"`

---

**Now about the request:**

You could do this in a shorter way, but I chose this longer path, to illustrate the idea.

1. Gather the settings' information
2. Set a reference to both columns and rows
3. Find the intersection between them
4. Look for non empty cells in that range and hide their columns and rows

**Code:**

```
Public Sub DynamicallyHideCells()
    
    Dim settingsSheet As Worksheet
    Dim reportSheet As Worksheet
    
    Dim targetColumnsRange As Range
    Dim targetRowsRange As Range
    Dim targetRange As Range
    Dim targetCell As Range
    
    Dim reportSheetName As String
    Dim reportColumnsAddr As String
    Dim reportRowsAddr As String
    
    ' Set a reference to the settings sheet
    Set settingsSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    
    ' Gather the report sheet's name
    reportSheetName = settingsSheet.Range("C7").Value
    
    ' Check the : between the two cells reference
    reportColumnsAddr = settingsSheet.Range("C8").Value & ":" & settingsSheet.Range("D8").Value
    
    ' Check the : between the two cells reference
    reportRowsAddr = settingsSheet.Range("C9").Value & ":" & settingsSheet.Range("D9").Value
    
    ' Set a reference to the report's sheet
    Set reportSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(reportSheetName)
    
    ' Set a reference to the report's columns
    Set targetColumnsRange = reportSheet.Range(reportColumnsAddr)
    
    ' Set a reference to the report's rows
    Set targetRowsRange = reportSheet.Range(reportRowsAddr)
    
    ' Find the range of cells to be evaluated
    Set targetRange = Intersect(targetColumnsRange, targetRowsRange)
    
    ' Loop through each cell and hide if not empty
    For Each targetCell In targetRange.Cells
    
        If targetCell.Value <> vbNullString Then
            targetCell.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
            targetCell.EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End If
    
    Next targetCell
    
    
End Sub
```

**EDIT:**

If you only need to hide the columns. Use the following code:

**EDIT 2:**

Added line to check if input cells are empty (' Check if either cell are empty and exit sub).

```
Public Sub HideColumns()
    
    Dim settingsSheet As Worksheet
    Dim reportSheet As Worksheet
    
    Dim targetColumnsRange As Range
    
    Dim reportSheetName As String
    Dim reportColumnsAddr As String
    
    ' Set a reference to the settings sheet
    Set settingsSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    
    ' Gather the report sheet's name
    reportSheetName = settingsSheet.Range("C7").Value
    
    ' Check the : between the two cells reference
    reportColumnsAddr = settingsSheet.Range("C8").Value & ":" & settingsSheet.Range("D8").Value
    
    ' Check if either cell are empty and exit sub
    If settingsSheet.Range("C8").Value = vbNullString Or settingsSheet.Range("D8").Value = vbNullString Then
        
        ' Set a reference to the report's sheet
        Set reportSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(reportSheetName)
    
        ' Set a reference to the report's columns
        Set targetColumnsRange = reportSheet.Range(reportColumnsAddr)
    
        ' Hide the columns in range
        targetColumnsRange.EntireColumn.Hidden = True


    Else

        ' Do something here

    End If
    
    
End Sub
```

Hope this is what you're looking for.

Let me know if it works.

Comment: Hi Ricardo, thank you for your help. The range which I want to hide might contain some data in it, so I will not be hiding empty cells. That's why I'm trying to give it a cell reference, since the data format will change from files to other. I'm trying to replace the value of TEST 1 in the range below    `TEST1 = "(" & Chr(34) & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C8").Value & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D8").Value & Chr(34) & ")"'` to this code, but I keep getting an error `Set allColumns = ReportSheet.Columns("N:S")
        allColumns.Hidden = True`. Thoughts on how to replace it?

Comment: What is TEST1 used for?

Comment: I need TEST1 = the range which rows to hide. For example, if I input in Cell C8:D8 the values N:X, it's because I want to hide the range N:X (I know TEST1 naming is terrible!!). The same applies for the Rows to hide. So the value of the TEST1 should replace what's in this code here `Set allColumns = ReportSheet.Columns("N:S") allColumns.Hidden = True`

Comment: My code hides the rows and columns of cells that are `NOT` empty based on the values recorded in the settings cells (C8:D8) and (C9:D9) that you mentioned. 

What you want in Test1 is `settingsSheet.Range("C8").Value & ":" & settingsSheet.Range("D8").Value` which is a line that I have in my code. You don't need to add the parenthesis nor the quotes. Test1 in your code should be a string. And a Range can take a string as a parameter -> Range(String).

Comment: Ummm, for example, I have data from columns A:M and some other data from N:S, so I want to hide the ones in N:S. However, sometimes that will change, in the future I might need to hide T:X instead. I hope this is clearer

Comment: Do you need to always hide the columns in the range that you define in the cells? Kinda lost here because in your original post you had:  `I would like to code not hide anything if the cells are empty` ... if that's the case, to hide them indistinctly, in my code just add this line: `targetColumnsRange.EntireColumn.Hidden = True` and delete the section where I loop through the cells.

Comment: Yes, the first condition will be hiding the rows that are defined in the range for both rows and columns. The second condition is that if no range is provided, then hide nothing. So if C8:DO are blank, then convert the whole sheet as is. Otherwise hide the rows/columns that are provided. Apologies for the confusion

Comment: Ok. See my edit. if you need to clarify your question. Please use the [edit] link.

Comment: That did work. However, I had to change `Set reportSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(reportSheetName)` to `Set reportsheet = Sheets(reportSheetName)` since I was always getting an error. The code works well so far, although it looks like a spaghetti!! Will implement the same logic using Rows to hide.

Comment: Hi Ricardo, a follow up question. When I leave the range for columns and rows to hide empty on the settingsheet (when I don't wanna hide anything and show all) I get "Run-time error 1004: Application-defined or object-defined error" I tried inserting an If statement, but didn't seem to work. Basically if my cell reference is empty, I would like to convert everything to PDF without hiding anything.  `If reportColumnsAddr <> vbNullString Then

targetColumnsRange.EntireColumn.Hidden = True

End If

If targetRowsRange <> vbNullString Then

targetRowsRange.EntireRow.Hidden = True

End If`

Comment: Here 'Set targetColumnsRange = reportSheet.Range(reportColumnsAddr)' when I'm deleting the inputs I lot columns to hide. Both hide columns and rows work perfectly when provided with a value. But doesn't work when they are not

Comment: add If `targetRowsRange = vbNullString Then exit sub` before

Comment: Hello again, I'm still getting an error Run Time 91. Basically if I don't provide any columns or rows to hide, I don't want the code to hide anything and to continue the code, which is converting Excel sheets into PDFs without exiting the sub. Apologies for the confusion if any

Comment: That is good, however, I need it to continue the Sub rather than exiting it. I tried playing around with it but I keep getting errors. How about I put my query into a new post instead?

Comment: Hi Ricardo, I was able to fix the problem, and add more If statements to the tool. I'm facing a new error now, hoping to get your thoughts about it [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60332267/vba-run-time-error-9-when-sheet-name-does-not-match-the-target-sheet-name) THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

Replace "" with """" :

```
TEST1 = "(" & """" & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C8").Value & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
.Range("D8").Value & """" & ")"
```